# Почему в emacs такая маленькая табуляция (2 пробела) и как её увеличить?

Tags: emacs, linux

Очень хочется писать в emacs, но мешает маленькая табуляция. Как её увеличить?

Comment: Если очень хочется работать в emacs, то вам следует разбираться в нем самому, а не по каждому поводу задавать вопрос, посколько вопросов у вас будет очень много. Чтобы разобраться самому начните читать документацию, ссылку я вам уже дал в другом вопросе, и пользуйтесь поиском по интернету.


Comment: Как уже сказали документации (на русском языке) очень много, и не стоит по каждому пустяку писать здесь.

Comment: Добавьте информации в вопросе для понимания проблемы. Какая major-mode, version и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Размер табуляции, например, в 4 пробела (в ~/.emacs) :

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
```